# Extract two combined dates and times from a string

Tags: r

Could you please let me know how I can extract date and time from ("2015-08-11 03:14:00 UTC--2015-08-11 04:14:00 UTC"). Note that this string contains a time interval with two dates and two times. I would like to break it down into 4 individual strings such as Date 1, Time 1, Date 2, Time 2 and then store them in 4 separate vectors.

Thanks.

Comment: In R a time object must have a date associated with it.  For further analysis I would suggest keeping the time part with the date and storing the result as a POSIXct object.

Comment: Now I have "2015-08-10 07:14:00 UTC" as Chr and I used the following but I get NA in all.   data$datetime = as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').

Comment: This works now: as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
x <- "2015-08-11 03:14:00 UTC--2015-08-11 04:14:00 UTC"
y <- strsplit(x, "--")[[1]]

dates <- as.Date(y)
times <- strftime(y, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

You never mentioned whether you need functional dates and times from your input string.  If you need to simply parse each portion of your timestamp then using `gsub` is one option.

```
x <- "2015-08-11 03:14:00 UTC--2015-08-11 04:14:00 UTC"
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "--"))
dates <- sapply(y, function(x) gsub("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x))
times <- sapply(y, function(x) gsub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.*)", "\\1", x))
dates
[1] "2015-08-11" "2015-08-11"
times
[1] "03:14:00 UTC" "04:14:00 UTC"
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks. I found a simpler way as well: we can define an string and use substr(str1,...,...).